# How to set default value with InterfaceGL?

Tags: c++, parameters, cinder

So, doing something like this:

```
   paramsInterface->addParam("EpsilonUpper",&mKinectModule->mEpsilon,"min=0 max=1 step=.001");
```

Seems to set the value to whatever the cpp class assigns. Is there a parameter string way of doing it? Its just nice/quicker to see your initializers in the same spot, i.e. where the initializer string containing your min/max is.

The Doc
http://libcinder.org/docs/v0.8.2/classcinder_1_1params_1_1_interface_gl.html

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not.

P.S. under the hood, the Params interface in Cinder is an implementation of AntTweakBar. You can see the available parameters [here](http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/tools%3aanttweakbar%3avarparamsyntax), though there's not a 1:1 feature mapping between AntTweakBar and Cinder's Params class.